# Where to place Winsock declarations in Win32 gui program?

Tags: winapi, winsock

So I have a win32 project with the Windows procedure and everything.
I want the client to be able to connect to a server, but at the same time to be able to process window messages.
So I already figured this part out. I will Asynchronous sockets for the client.
The only question I have is, where do i put the WSADATA, server structure, and socket() declarations?
In the WinMain function? Windows procedure?

In short, how do I integrate a winsock implementation into winapi gui? How do i combine the two? All the tutorials ive found online only deal with either Winsock OR winapi, they never seem to mix the two.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Windows SDK has such examples (maybe in older versions of SDK)

Comment: What language are you using? In C++, I tend to put my winsock code inside a class - it makes it nice and self-contained.  I also make it run in a separate thread - this way comms doesn't lock up the GUI and vice versa.